# Old entries containing UTF8 characters saved incorrectly in UTF8 database

Tags: mysql, unicode

Ok, so I've ensured that my MySQL (5.1.61) database is UTF8, the table is UTF8, the field is UTF8, and the MySQL client's charset is set to UTF8. I can store and retrieve UTF8 entries successfully. I've also ensured my terminal's encoding is set to UTF8.

```
CREATE TABLE `cities` (
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

The issue when it comes to the 200,000 entries that already exist in the database. It appears the people we inherited the project from messed up a lot of the encoding, actually saving a string like `Hörby` as `HÃ¶rby` where `Ã` and `¶` are valid UTF8 characters. That is, **MySQL is receiving a UTF8 string of `HÃ¶rby` and is storing it as such**. Here is an example where the first entry is one of the old entries, and the second is us inserting "`Hörby`" into the database with everything set to UTF8:

```
mysql> INSERT INTO cities SET name = 'Hörby';
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM cities;
+----------+
| name     |
+----------+
| HÃ¶rby   | <--- old entry
| Hörby    | <--- new entry
+----------+
```

What can we do to convert the squished characters into what they once were? We're pretty much ready to do anything at this point, but re-typing all 200,000 records is not feasible.

Comment: Do you have any way to determine which records are "old" ones (predating your database change) and which are "new"?

Comment: @eggyal: Yes, around 99% of the database contains the old records. We can manually re-add the new entries at this point in time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you had previously stored `utf8` encoded strings in a `latin1` column, then converted that column to `utf8`.  To fix that:

1. Convert the data back to `latin1`:

   ```
   ALTER TABLE cities MODIFY name varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1;
   ```
2. Change the column type to UTF-8 without altering the data (going via `binary`):

   ```
   ALTER TABLE cities MODIFY name varchar(255) CHARACTER SET binary;
   ALTER TABLE cities MODIFY name varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8;
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `REPLACE` function in MYSQL.

Something like -

```
`UPDATE cities
 SET name = REPLACE(name, 'Ã¶', 'ö');`
```

Comment: Sadly this would involve finding all of the bad characters, figuring out what they were supposed to be, then writing a `REPLACE` for every bad character.

Comment: There is no other option. How would you tell MySQL this is good, keep it and this is bad, replace it?